# How can I change log level of single logger in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, logback

I wanna read `spring` property and based on this property change log level for some packages (not for root logger). How can I implement it using logback?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

See top related question: [SLF4J - Logback: How to configure loggers in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448673/slf4j-logback-how-to-configure-loggers-in-runtime)

More specific `((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger("abc.xyz")) .setLevel(Level.XXX)` should do the trick.

I'm not sure what your use case is, but I prefer to use the JMX interface: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/jmxConfig.html.