# Set log level for scala-logging

Tags: scala, logging, scala-logging

My console app takes a `log-level=<LEVEL>` option. Looking at some [examples in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18105362/2890093), it looks like changing SLF4J logger level is generally possible, but with [scala-logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging#using-scala-logging) library it seems like this is not the case - regardless of how I create the logger it doesn't have `setLevel` method available. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

The library needs a logging backend (you can check out the prerequisites). Once you define it, you can set the logging level via a configuration file, for example:

```xml
// src/main/resources/logback.xml
<configuration>    
  <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"/>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

This will result in setting the log level to `DEBUG` for that particular logger. Anyway, this should work if you're using the [slf4j](https://logback.qos.ch/) backend. I hope this helps you.

Comment: But this way I can only set logging level at build time, right? What about runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this using logback. Alternatively you can use a log4j backend which provides the method you are looking for. This works fine because scala-logging can work with a log4j backend :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838108/2890093) I used this piece of code and it did the work for me:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.{Level,Logger}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

LoggerFactory
  .getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
  .asInstanceOf[Logger]
  .setLevel(Level.INFO)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger

Comment: This answer is deprecated as the `Logger` instance does not have a method `setLevel` anymore.