# SLF4J: isDebugEnabled() not working

Tags: java, slf4j, jmx

My java application which is using SLF4J is running on Unix box and my code has entries like :

```
if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                    LOG.debug("There is nothing in the cache for " + quote.getObject().getObjectId() + " - using the init quote");
```

I try to enable logging at ALL or DEBUG or TRACE via JMX but still above log statement doesn't get printed. All statement without "`isDebugEnabled()`" get printed.

Any ideas what can be done to enable these log statements? I cannot change logback.xml and only use JMX to change log levels.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102898/how-can-i-change-log-level-of-single-logger-in-runtime) may help

Comment: Can you attach a debugger to see how LOG is configured?  Also note that logback can be configured to expose its configuration over JMX

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, when you say "All statements without isDebugEnabled() get printed", you mean this gets printed:

```
LOG.debug("There is nothing in the cache for " + quote.getObject().getObjectId() + " - using the init quote");
```

but this doesn't:

```
if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
    LOG.debug("There is nothing in the cache for " + quote.getObject().getObjectId() + " - using the init quote");
```

That doesn't make sense, since `LOG.debug()` would internally do the equivalent of `if (isDebugEnabled())`. Therefore you should run your code through a debugger to find out what is going on.

If you mean that `LOG.debug(...)` does NOT get printed but other levels do, you should follow the link in @a_a's comment to set the level programmatically to Debug.