# Logback log created in same directory as far at build time

Tags: java, logging, gradle, logback

I created a command line tool that ships as an executable jar. When someone uses my tool I do not know where the jar will be located. All of the logging is being done with logback. I want my log file to go to the same directory as the jar file no matter where the jar is located and no matter what the current directory is.

My current logback.xml files looks like this.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>admintool.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the log to go where the jar is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to remove the slash from `/admintool.log` ?

Comment: Yes, it still puts it in the current directory.

Comment: I think you should consider configuring logback in runtime. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448673/slf4j-logback-how-to-configure-loggers-in-runtime

Comment: Sorry correction: the code fails with that slash. Without the slash it puts the log file in the current directory. I will update my question sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to provide property values to Logback configuration during runtime:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly

You need to create a class that implements `PropertyDefiner` interface and returns location of the jar

```
public class MyPropertyDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {
    @Override
    public String getPropertyValue() {
        return MyPropertyDefiner.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
    }
}
```

In your logback.xml you can specify something like this

```
<configuration>
    <define name="jarLocation" class="MyPropertyDefiner"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${jarLocation}</file>
        ...
    </appender>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: When I did this the getFile() method could not be found. Is there something else I need to include?

Comment: It should be either getPath() or getFile(). I corrected the answer