# Java class cast exception: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger

Tags: java, maven, log4j, logback, slf4j

I have been trying to figure this out but it escapes me completely. Been searching on for days now.

Most of the answers on stackoverflow states that I exclude the slf4j library. 
Sources:
[Getting Exception org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891737/getting-exception-org-apache-logging-slf4j-slf4jloggercontext-cannot-be-cast-to) 
[ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433246/classcastexception-org-slf4j-impl-log4jloggeradapter-cannot-be-cast-to-ch-qos-l)

However the stack trace does not say that. 
I am assuming I am doing something wrong within the LoggerUtil class and while using it in the main class this error shows up.

Unfortunately I do not have any control over the web application (I am assuming it is built using log4j). I am building a plugin and it hits a wsdl with response I parse. Locally I am able to run without any issues and the 2 files I create work as intended.

[image]

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
at com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin.LoggerUtil.createLogger(LoggerUtil.java:27)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin.LoggerUtil.lambda$createLoggerFor$0(LoggerUtil.java:23)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1118)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin.LoggerUtil.createLoggerFor(LoggerUtil.java:23)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin.Integration.init(Integration.java:51)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin.Integration.<init>(Integration.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.manager.impl.PluginManagerBean.executeJavaServerFunction(PluginManagerBean.java:457)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.manager.impl.PluginManagerBean.executePluginByEntityAndName(PluginManagerBean.java:312)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy188.executePluginByEntityAndName(Unknown Source)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.web.controller.FormServicesController.executeServerFuntion(FormServicesController.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.web.filter.SecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecurityHeadersFilter.java:19)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at com.idmlogic.sigma.web.filter.CsrfHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfHeaderFilter.java:31)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom file where I have excluded org.slf4j and slf4j-log4j12 I have tried without as well. But the error still remains.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>serviceplatformen.integration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.2</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.idmlogic.sigma</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigma.plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sigma.plugin-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>CprLookupService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlLocation>/wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
                    <!-- Keep generated files -->
                    <keep>true</keep>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceDestDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated/cxf</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The logger util class which creates the log file and appends

```
package com.idmlogic.sigma.plugin;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * The <code>LoggerUtil</code> creates log file if the file is not created.
 * */
public class LoggerUtil {

    private static Map<String, Logger> loggerMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Logger createLoggerFor(String name, String file, String info, String pattern) {
        return loggerMap.computeIfAbsent(name, a -> createLogger(a, file, info, pattern));
    }

    private static Logger createLogger(String name, String file, String info, String pattern) {
        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
        logger.addAppender(getiLoggingEventFileAppender(file, pattern));
        logger.setLevel(Level.valueOf(info));
        logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */
        return logger;
    }

    private static FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> getiLoggingEventFileAppender(String file, String pattern) {
        FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        fileAppender.setFile(file);
        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        fileAppender.setEncoder(getPatternLayoutEncoder(lc, pattern));
        fileAppender.setContext(lc);
        fileAppender.start();
        return fileAppender;
    }

    private static PatternLayoutEncoder getPatternLayoutEncoder(LoggerContext lc, String pattern) {
        PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        ple.setPattern(pattern);
        ple.setContext(lc);
        ple.start();
        return ple;
    }

}
```

The main class where I use the logger and I assume breaks is the following method:

```
private static Logger cprSearchLog;
    private static Properties properties;
    private static Logger errorLog;
/**
     * Init create an errorlog and a cprSearchLog and reads the CprSoeg.request file
     * @param properties contains all attributes required be the module
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException containing a IOException if the CprSoeg.request file was not found
     */
    void init(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        errorLog = LoggerUtil.createLoggerFor("errorLog", (String) Objects.requireNonNull(properties.getProperty("ErrorLog"),"ErrorLog can not be null"), properties.getProperty("ErrorLog.Level","INFO"), properties.getProperty("ErrorLog.Pattern","%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n"));
        cprSearchLog = LoggerUtil.createLoggerFor("cprSearchLog", (String) Objects.requireNonNull(properties.getProperty("CPRSearchLog"), "CPRSearchLog can not be null"), properties.getProperty("CPRSearchLog.Level","INFO"), properties.getProperty("CPRSearchLog.Pattern","%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n"));
        try {
            cprSoegRequest = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("CprSoeg.request")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CprSoeg.request was not found", e);
        }
    }
```

I also found that JBoss does not work well with logback. Then again I do not have the permission to work with the server itself. 
[Logback and Jboss 7 - don't work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518687/logback-and-jboss-7-dont-work-together/19695680#19695680)

Another option is to use log4j but a little confused about using that too. Haven't tried yet though. 
Any suggestions please is really useful.

Comment: JBOSS is using a private implementation of the `org.slf4j.Logger`
named `org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger`.

Since the JBOSS logging jars are in front of the app jars on the Classpath, the call to `LoggerFactory` is landing in the JBOSS private implementation and not in Logback.  I don't know how to "fix" this.

Comment: Did you try adding exclusions?