# Dynamically change Logback level for web app running on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j, logback

I have a `logback.xml` in the resources folder of my java web application which is running on Tomcat 7. Is there a way to change the debug level of some class of the application dynamically as the application is running?

The standard thing to do it is a normal java jar running from the CLI is to just edit `logback.xml` with say vim and after a while the log is updated. Is this possible with tomcat as I tried it and id does not seem to work.

Is there any better way?

Comment: you can configure logback programmatically, that is the simplest way.

Comment: can you please point me to some tutorials or code explaining this?

Comment: this should be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448673/slf4j-logback-how-to-configure-loggers-in-runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this is your application to change the level:

```
Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

For specifying the package name as logger-name.

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger myPackageLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("com.mypackage");
myPackageLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Is there a way to chose the specific package since my logback gives me this ability? To change for specific classes or even packages.

Comment: That did it. Excellent solution. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems not to working at all. I have a spring rest controller and this import: `import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;` and the I buitl a method with `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);      root.setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.toLevel(arg));` , but with no effect, starting from logback.xnl with DEBUG, no changes to INFO have effect, system stays at DEBUG.