# How to update logback.xml in java programmatically

Tags: java, xml, slf4j, logback

I want to update logback.xml in java programmatically, I tried to update sing DOM API but got an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: An attempt is made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:351)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:288)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:238)
at XMLUtils.add(XMLUtils.java:49)
```

Java Result: 1

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue, and is that any possibility to achieve this via logback API.

Comment: It might not be, that's kind of the idea of a config. You might want to post more of your actual *problem* instead of the thing you're trying to do to solve it.

Comment: I have something dynamics logger to add, but in running state its append the logger but i also want to update that xml file too

Comment: Update what XML file? logback.xml? That doesn't answer my question, you're just telling me you want to update logback again when I asked what problem you're trying to solve that requires updating logback.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448673/slf4j-logback-how-to-configure-loggers-in-runtime?rq=1

Comment: please check my answer again what i said, I said i have something business logic to add dynamic logger, so i also want to add those logger in xml file to for future restart app

Comment: I made the solution, thanks everyone :)